# Java Spring Tool Suite multiple controllers

Tags: java, spring

I have an application with two packages.  In the first package, I have 2 controllers.  The first controller is called APIController.java which displays a view.  This is the code of the controller:

```
package com.dogo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping()
public class APIController {

    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public String apiChat() {
        return "apiChat.html";
    }

}
```

The second controller is called HomeController.java which I use to display the index.html page.  This is the code:

```
package com.dogo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index.html";
    }

}
```

The second package also contains a controller called MessageController.java.  This is used to update a dao database based on the parameters passed in the url.  This is the code for this controller:

```
package com.dogo.chat;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping()
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    MessageRepository dao;

    @GetMapping("/chat")
    public List<Message> getMessages(){
        List<Message> foundMessages = dao.findAll();
        return foundMessages;
    }

    @PostMapping("/chat")
    public ResponseEntity<Message> postMessage(@RequestBody Message message) 
   {

        // Saving to DB using an instance of the repo Interface.
        Message createdMessage = dao.save(message);

        // RespEntity crafts response to include correct status codes.
        return ResponseEntity.ok(createdMessage);
    }


    @GetMapping("/chat/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Message> getMessage(@PathVariable(value="id") 
 Integer id){
        Message foundMessage = dao.findOne(id);

        if(foundMessage == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().header("Message","Nothing found with that id").build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(foundMessage);
    }


    @DeleteMapping("/message/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Message> deleteMessage(@PathVariable(value="id") Integer id){
        Message foundMessage = dao.findOne(id);

        if(foundMessage == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().header("Message","Nothing found with that id").build();
        }else {
            dao.delete(foundMessage);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }  
}
```

When I type http://localhost:8080/api into my browser, the apiChat.html page is displayed.  When I change the @RequestMapping() in APIController.java to @RequestMapping("/api") and I type http://localhost:8080/api/api I get a 404 error.  I had expected the apiChat.html page to be displayed.  What am I missing?  Thank you.

Comment: Why does your title mention "multiple Controllers"?

Comment: I just set up a test project and it works fine, I guess this is not the root of your problem

Comment: @daniu I just edited my post to include more code from the files I have in my application